# Factory reset EPSON EXPRESSION PHOTO XP-750

Tags: printer, factory-defaults, inkjet-printer

Is there any way to make a factory reset to EPSON EXPRESSION PHOTO XP-750?

The problem is that the printheads are really not aligned, and there is no way to align them.
The print quality is well but it print all things ghosting.

So I would try to factory reset the printer.

Thank you to all.

The printer is this:

[Printer](http://www.epson.it/it/it/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/overview/12224)

Comment: Google is your friend - http://www.epson.co.uk/gb/en/viewcon/corporatesite/store/products/mainunits/faq/12224/1888

Comment: If the issue is aligning the printheads, how to do that is at the same web site.  For Windows: http://www.epson.co.uk/gb/en/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/faq/12224/1097.  For Mac: http://www.epson.co.uk/gb/en/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/faq/12224/2110